# Inserting value in a certain column

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

I have a php program and i want to insert values into certain column.
here is my table.

```
form_no | fullname | january | february | march | april | may | june | july
11111     smith, john
```

what is the right query code in doing this?
and the right way in checking if the cell already contains a value?
raw table:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B99TeByt30n2eHdLM0FER210cWM/edit?usp=sharing

and here is my code in which i also tried to check if that cell has already a value.

```
$value_result = mysql_query("SELECT january FROM table_2014 WHERE form_no = '$formnumber'");
$value_rownum = mysql_num_rows($value_result);
if (!$value_result) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
if ( $value_rownum > 0 ) {
    echo "Already contributed!";
} else {
    $sql = "UPDATE `table_2014` SET january = '$contri_amnt' WHERE form_no = '$formnumber'";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
         die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: And the question, if you may... ?

Comment: Whats is your question? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why do you have tables with the year in the name and denormalized columns? You really should look at redesigning your tables here.

Comment: do you have any suggestions in designing my tables.coz i have no idea @sean lange

Comment: Not sure what you are storing but some like a Form table to hold the FormNo and the FullName. Then FormDetails or something like that with FormNo (foreign key) and a date (maybe this is a year and month). They way you have it you have to query different columns for different months and different tables for different years. This is not very manageable in the long run.

Comment: here is the screenshot of the table that i want to be stored https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B99TeByt30n2eHdLM0FER210cWM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: here is a pic of the table that i want to be stored https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B99TeByt30n2eHdLM0FER210cWM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Even if January is NULL you will still get a row, so counting the rows will give you 1, and you will never update it.

You need to use mysql_fetch_assoc or mysql_fetch_object to check if the result actually has a value.
OR, change your query to

SELECT january FROM table_2014 WHERE form_no = '$formnumber' AND january IS NOT NULL